# How to install wifi adaptor on Linux

Tags: linux, wifi, realtek

### How to Install the TP-Link AC600 Dual Band WiFi Adapter on Linux.

This is for the SUCCESSFUL installation of the TP-Link AC600 Dual Band WIFI Adapter on a fresh install of Ubuntu Xenerial (Lubuntu) on the i686 Linux Distro

```
Kernal: 4.15.0-45-generic
Linux OS: Lubuntu Xenial Xerus
Linux Version: 16.04.1
Build: #48
Device Manufact: 2357
Device Model: 011F
Full Name: TP LINK ARCHER T2U v3
```

A number of solutions are advocated, all claiming to work. But they many not work , or they may have an unfinished codebase causing errors. However I have formulated a solution that WILL work on Lubuntu Distros of 16.04 and above.

Answer (score 0):

### TP-LINK ARCHER T2U V3 (2357:011F) Installation Procedure.

#### LINUX XENIAL 32BIT (UBUNTU 16.04)

> ### The Process - The Online Install
>
> (if you have access to the net with Ethernet, 
> it will be a doddle... but if not. prepare that thumb drive, and those thumbs!!)

---

#### Collect the background packages

> The packages we will need to collect are listed below:

```
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install -y binutils build-essential cpp-5 dkms dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-5 
sudo apt install -y gcc gcc-5_5.3.1 gcc-5_5.4.0 gcc-5-base git git-man libalgorithm-diff-perl
sudo apt install -y libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan2 libatomic1
sudo apt install -y libc6 libc6-dev libcc1-0_5.3.1 libcc1-0_5.4.0 libc-dev-bin libcilkrts5
sudo apt install -y libdpkg-perl libelf1 liberror-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl
sudo apt install -y libgcc-5-dev libgomp1 libitm1 libmpx0 libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev 
sudo apt install -y libstdc++6 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
```

*Note: if you export these packages alongside the drivers you will have a standalone package to **"take with you"**...*

```
# For offline installs place packages into a folder and 
# execute a multiple install action by doing the following

sudo FOLDERPATH="YourFolderPathHere" 
sudo apt install ./$FOLDERPATH/*.deb
```

#### Select the relevant driver package.

Next we want to get our driver! now, so far, the one ive found that works, it is definately ***NOT*** the **airmon-ng/rtl8812au** one used for injecting packets, Nor was it the **abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux**  one, although it did compile but it just wouldn't load are all our hopes lost?!...

No! it would appear we have another contender in the world of patched up drivers from manufactures that dont even support their own products....

[Sorry TP-LINK, but if you release a product, and expect us all to fix these products, thats a class action waiting to happen.]

### The Driver!

## [RTL8812AU-1](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1)

## Driver credit goes to JeremyB31 from [GIT](https://github.com/jeremyb31/)

*Now we need to clone into this driver package*

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812au-1.git
```

Enter into the folder.

```
cd rtl8812au-1
```

Install!

```
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot and your done.